# How to access the context menu for an attachment in Outlook "New Message dialog

Tags: outlook, vsto

I have an Outlook VSTO addin.  I can successfully modify the context menu for attachments "received" by the user (either in the email message received or in the preview window.)  I cannot figure out how to access the context menu for an attachment for a message being "sent"

Anyone know of the idMso for this context menu or another way to get access to it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all context menus can be customized by developers (there is no idMso values published). You can find possible context menus customizations described in the [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks...but that begs the question: can this context menu be customized?  I'm familiar with the link you provided.

Comment: I'd replacing the question with "is the idMso available for the context menu". Only context menus with well-known dims values can be customized. Unfortunately MS didn't share the idMso value for that context menu. So the answer is no.

Comment: I phrased the question the way I did to make sure there was no other way to access the context menu if the idMso was not available....i.e. is there a workaround?   But thanks for your answer.